# OAuth2 authorization behind the LoadBalancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, load-balancing, spring-oauth2

I run 2 instances of OAuth2 Authorization servers behind the Load Balancer (F5). I'm using `JdbcTokenStore`. Everything works just fine, but sometimes I get an error "*Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Invalid authorization code: XXXXX*".
My servise works fine if I run only one instance and sometimes fails if I run two instances. It seems that if load balancer mixes requests to different servers during the authorization process everything fails.

[image]

My question is, how can I solve this kind of problem? Should I use **stickysession** in the load balancer? If yes, when how could I ensure high availability with **stickysession**? Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using already implemented oauth2 authorization servers. In that case you need to find out if they are using session when authenticating, or some token system based on keys signature. Difference is that when you use keys signature token, like JWT with signature for example, the connections are stateless. Server only validates incoming tokens in requests with signing key and therefore information about that connection doesn't have to be stored in memory/db. Note that two servers must use same signing key so authentication is valid in each server. In that case you don't need to use sticky session in load balancer.

You could implement custom oauth2 authorization server with authentication model based on JWT with signature keys. You could implement session authentication but two servers would have to use shared jdbc token store, so each server knows about valid authentications of the other. Or otherwise you will have to use sticky session as you proposed in your answer

Oauth2 resource server for example is based on JWT with signing keys.